# why this is giving an error?

Tags: c, macros, inline

I don't know why this is giving me  error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
#include<stdio.h>
inline int square(int x){ 
    return x*x;
}

int main() {
    int x = 36/square(6);
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine in Dev-C IDE.

Comment: but not in gcc...:(...what that error exactly mean??

Comment: It is a linker error. What command do you use to compile?

Comment: In a nutshell, change the `inline` to `static inline`. See the linked answer for the technical details.